# datetime, string format in Python/Pandas

Tags: pandas

New to Python/Pandas. Just wondering if it is correct to assume the following are the same:

```
pd.to_datetime(str(20061231), format='%Y%m%d')
```

and

```
pd.Timestamp('2006-12-31')
```

also

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime(str(20061231), format='%Y%m%d')
```

`str(20061231)` of course produces a string, and is the same as  `start_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')`

Comment: "if ... are the same" - please specify "the same". E.g., from one point of view, the use different code, so they are not the same. Are the results the same?

Comment: Visual inspection suggests they produce the same results! So I am guessing this is just Pandas allows users to achieve the same outcome in multiple ways.

Comment: Or maybe `pd.Timestamp` is calling `pd.to_datetime` insternally or vice versa.. The answer really depends on the definition of "the same". Strictly speaking, they are not the same, because the code is not the same. If you are concerned about the results and the results are the same, then you can tell they are the same